# Add tensor to another by repeating along axis

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a tensor `out` with shape:

```
torch.Size([4, 644, 25])
```

and another one `x` with shape:

```
torch.Size([4, 161, 25])
```

I want to add `x` to `out` 4 times, something like:

```
        out[:, 0:161] += x
        out[:, 161:322] += x
        out[:, 322:483] += x
        out[:, 483:644] += x
```

Is there some one-liner that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) here:

```
out += np.tile(x, (1,out.shape[1]//x.shape[1],1))
```

Or using `pytorch`'s [`repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html):

```
out += x.repeat(1,out.shape[1]//x.shape[1],1)
```